# Getting Facebook user info after login in objective c

Tags: objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to get the user name, email and picture from Facebook after login. Login and permissions works fine.

I tried using:

```
FBSession
```

But Im getting `"user of undeclared FBSession"` as I was trying to implement:

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
   NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
   NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {
         NSString *firstName = user.first_name;
         NSString *lastName = user.last_name;
         NSString *facebookId = user.id;
         NSString *email = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
         NSString *imageUrl = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", facebookId];
     }
 }];}
```

Found it here: [How to get user info from Facebook SDK in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111993/how-to-get-user-info-from-facebook-sdk-in-ios)

Any ideas how can I achive this? Or why am I getting undeclared for Facebook elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the new facebook sdk and new graph api you have to use access tokens

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {


    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"picture,email,birthday,gender,name"}] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id res, NSError *error)
     {
         if (!error) {



             FBID = [res objectForKey:@"id"];
             FBDOB = [res objectForKey:@"birthday"];
             FBEMAIL = [res objectForKey:@"email"];
             FBGENDER = [res objectForKey:@"gender"];
             FBUSERNAME = [res objectForKey:@"name"];


         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
         }}];
}
```

check out this link on fetching data from facebook 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph